# Rails Validation - :without option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, devise, omniauth

I am trying (and failing miserably) to incorporate devise with omniauth into my Rails 4 app.

My current effort is to get the system outlined in this tutorial working. http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

The current problem I have is a validation error - which is preventing the server from starting.

I have included this validation in my user model:

```
  validates_format_of :email, :without => TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update
```

When I try to start the server, I get this error:

```
Exiting
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:44:in `check_options_validity': A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :without (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:21:in `check_validity!'
```

When I check the docs on this, the guidance note says:

```
:without - Regular expression that if the attribute does not match will result in a successful validation. This can be provided as a proc or lambda returning regular expression which will be called at runtime.
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of

I don't know what this note means (I don't understand a single thing in the API documentation - it's all written at a level of sophistication well above my grasp).

Can anyone see the error in this validation?

Comment: it should be `validates_format_of :email, :without => /TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX/, on: :update ` you miss regexp `//`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
validates_format_of :email, :without => /TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX/, on: :update
```

you miss regexp `//`

As Per document

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_format_of